# Google Analytics inpage_linkid script tag ID is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, google-analytics

I have the following code in the `<head>` of my HTML

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  var pluginUrl = '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
  _gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '<%"WEBSITE"%>']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%"ANALYTICS_ACCOUNT"%>']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

This automatically creates the Google Analytics code.  However, one of the scripts it adds to the page doesn't have an ID.

```js
<script id="undefined" type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js" ></script>
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a reason this is happening and how I could prevent it.

Comment: What does your raw HTML output once those variables are in place?